# how to increment date from a to b?

Tags: bash, shell-script, date

I have 2 dates, `start=20190903` & `end=20210912`
and want to increment till start approaches the end, increment is 13 days.

have following code, but it exceeds end.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

start="20190903"
end="20210912"

startdate="$(date -d ${start} +'%Y-%m-%d')"
enddate="$(date -d ${end} +'%Y-%m-%d')"
echo ${startdate}
echo ${enddate}

while [ "${startdate}" < "${enddate}" ]; do
    echo ${startdate}
    startdate="$( date -d "${startdate} + 13 days" +'%Y-%m-%d')"
done
```

Comment: didn't bash complain about no such file named 2021-09-12?

Comment: @UncleBilly it didn't,  it kept printing beyond end date. Or gave error about unary operation etc

Comment: or didn't you consider "relevant"? anyways, just using double brackets `while [[ ... ]]` will probably fix your script.

Comment: then it's most likely that you created such a file when you used `>` instead of `<` in a previous version of the script ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Uncle Billy's comments, `[` is a regular command, so your use of `<` is standard input redirection. If you didn't get a `bash: line 9: 2021-09-12: No such file or directory` error, it's likely that you had created that file with a previous use of `>`. If that's the case, then

```
[ "${startdate}" < "${enddate}" ]
```

evaluates the same as

```
[ "${startdate}" ]
```

which is truthy as long as `$startdate` is not unset or empty. So, you have an infinite loop.

Changing to using `[[` as in

```
while [[ "${startdate}" < "${enddate}" ]]; do
```

fixes this because that's a special form with its own syntax instead of a regular command and `<`/`>` aren't parsed as redirections then.

EDIT: `[[` is a bash-ism. If you want this to work with `[` so it's POSIX-compatible, you could use `-lt`. However, since that does numerical comparison instead of lexicographical like `<` does, you'd have to remove the `-`s from your date format:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

startdate="20190903"
enddate="20210912"

echo ${startdate}
echo ${enddate}

while [ "${startdate}" -lt "${enddate}" ]; do
    echo ${startdate}
    startdate="$( date -d "${startdate} + 13 days" +'%Y%m%d')"
done
```

In your case, with such a change, you end up with less code, since you no longer need to turn `start` into `startdate` and same with `end`/`enddate`.

EDIT 2: Another option seems to be to escape `<` as in `[ "${startdate}" \< "${enddate}" ]`, but that seems to only work for bash. It's not POSIX and it fails on zsh, at least.

Comment: Or use `-gt`and `-lt` for that POSIX feeling

Comment: @roaima Yes, though that would require a bigger change like poinck's to use Unix timestamps instead of ISO.

Comment: You could also use `'<'` or `\<` within `[ ... ]`.

Comment: @zevzek True, and they end up with less lines, too. Good call. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @they I didn't realize bash supported that, but it seems only bash does.

Comment: Yeah, it's not standard. It's documented for the `test` built-in.

Comment: Interesting, I get that making it POSIX-compatible is a good thing to do, but it looks like that compromises are made, too, like escaping the `<` sign and not able to use ISO-8601 date strings. Granted, my solution converts to seconds. But I am courious: Are there any other problems here with `[[` and `]]` that I am not aware of? I use it everywhere, because I read somewhere that shell builtins are faster.

Comment: Ok, I have found something: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059265/whats-the-problem-with-bashisms . Now, I might have to unlearn things. /:

Answer (score 5):

By comparing the `startdate+interval` with the end you prevent exeeding it.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

start="20190903"
end="20210912"
interval=1123200
    # 13 days = 13 * 24 * 60 *60

startdate=$( date --utc -d ${start} +%s )
enddate=$( date --utc -d ${end} +%s )

echo "$( date --utc -d @${startdate} +"%Y-%m-%d" ) (start)"
next=${startdate}
while [[ "$(( next+interval ))" -lt "${enddate}" ]] ; do
    next=$(( next+interval ))
    nextdate=$( date --utc -d @${next} +"%Y-%m-%d" )
    echo "${nextdate}"
done
echo "$( date --utc -d @${enddate} +"%Y-%m-%d" ) (end)"
```

I was not sure about your way of adding 13 days, so I changed it to seconds since 1970-01-01. At least now you know of another way of doing it.

Comment: Your interval in seconds isn't quite the same as `+ 13 days`. In a timezone on or near UTC that switches between summer time and winter time you could possibly end up reaching the 13 day interval either an hour early or an hour late. If you're going to use an absolute value it's worth treating dates as having midnight UTC (i.e. using `date --utc`)

Comment: I added `--utc` to deal with that. Thx, for pointing it out